# while developing window 8 store apps

Tags: window, windows-store-apps

I am new to window store App development, also i never work much in WPF but i have good experience in web development and WCF services. My next assignment is Window 8 Store App and i need to start it asap. we have WCF Restful service so we just need to create UI that has multiple pages.

so what i need to know is -
 1. Does MVVM pattern is suitable for such applications?
 2. Where can i find all controls of window store apps?
 3. Can HTML/Javascript can do the same as XAML/C# do ?

Answer (score 3):

**1.  Does MVVM pattern is suitable for such applications?**

Yes definitely. MVVM pattern can be apply in any XAML based development. There's plenty of framework available.

[Using the MVVM Pattern in Windows 8 - Laurent Bugnion (The mastermind behind MVVM Light)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx)

[MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com)

[Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com)

[Simple MVVM Toolkit](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/)

[JulMar MVVM Helpers + Behaviors](http://mvvmhelpers.codeplex.com/)

[Kona - Prism for Windows 8 Apps](http://konaguidance.codeplex.com/)

[Catel - application development platform with MVVM support](http://catel.codeplex.com/)

**2. Where can i find all controls of window store apps?**

[Controls list (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx)

[Controls list (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465453(v=win.10).aspx)

**3. Can HTML/Javascript can do the same as XAML/C# do ?**

It's a subject of discussion, I would suggest to read this stackoverflow question :  [Should I choose HTML5 or XAML for Metro development ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147012/should-i-choose-html5-or-xaml-for-metro-development)

Which language to choose is entirely depend upon you. Most of the functionality is available in both but JavaScript has more weight as you can use ANY JS in your project. THe controls are nearly same.

Comment: +1, for one place answer. thanks for collecting that info.

Comment: You are welcome Arun :)